# Hook to run code after a rule has been executed

Tags: 7, rules

I have a module which performs a specific task. The task itself runs fine, though it also needs to be exectued when a specific rule is triggered. Is there a hook for rules which I can use in my module to check if a specific rule has been fired?

Comment: Does http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21rules%21rules.api.php/function/hook_rules_action_info_alter/7 help? You could add some more callbacks to the action, making sure they run after the standard ones. See http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21rules%21rules.api.php/function/hook_rules_action_info/7 for details of the structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make that "specific task" as an action to a rule using [hook_rules_action_info](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21rules%21rules.api.php/function/hook_rules_action_info/7) and add that action for the rules which you want to exectue.

Comment: Yep, this ended up being the way to go. And it wasn't as difficult as I first thought.

Comment: is there an example of how to do this?